# Center horizontally li inside div with overflow:auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating something like a timeline, I have the following code so far:

```js
        $("#time-line-selector ul li a").click(function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            $("#time-line-selector ul li a").removeClass("active");

            $(this).addClass("active");

            var yearId = $(this).attr("data-id-selector");

            $("#time-line-container ul").animate({
                "margin-left": - ( (yearId - 1) * timeLineContentWidth)
            }, 1000);
        });
```

```css
#time-line-selector{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#time-line-selector ul{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#time-line-selector ul li{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
#time-line-selector ul li a{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
    padding: 16px 10px 8px 10px;
    color: #aeaeae;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#time-line-selector ul li a:before{
   display: block;
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   background: #e1e1e1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 1px;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
#time-line-selector ul li a:after{
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #aeaeae;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -5px 0 0 -5px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#time-line-selector ul li a:hover, #time-line-selector ul li a.active{
    background: #595959;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#time-line-selector ul li a:hover:after, #time-line-selector ul li a.active:after{
    background: #e62b28;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time-line-selector">
            <ul style="width: 1054px;"><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="1" data-year-selector="1935">1935</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="2" data-year-selector="1946">1946</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="3" data-year-selector="1995">1995</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="4" data-year-selector="1996">1996</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="5" data-year-selector="1997">1997</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="6" data-year-selector="1998">1998</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="7" data-year-selector="1999">1999</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="8" data-year-selector="1935">1935</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="9" data-year-selector="1946">1946</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="10" data-year-selector="1995">1995</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="11" data-year-selector="1996">1996</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="12" data-year-selector="1997">1997</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="13" data-year-selector="1998">1998</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="14" data-year-selector="1999">1999</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="15" data-year-selector="1935">1935</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="16" data-year-selector="1946">1946</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="17" data-year-selector="1995">1995</a></li><li class="time-line-selector"><a href="#" data-id-selector="18" data-year-selector="1996">1996</a></li></ul>
        </div>
```

What I like to do? I want that when the user clicks on some date, this date centralize using the scroll, does anyone know how to do this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvtsvr3e/

Comment: did you try to use `$(this).offset().left`?

Comment: this is what u meant? http://jsfiddle.net/vvtsvr3e/3/

Comment: @MorKadosh Something like that... however, when I click on the li, and this li should be centered within the parent got it?

Comment: @Morkadosh - great..! attempt friend.

Comment: @CaioKawasaki - can you update the answer in your JSFiddle link ? will helps lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add the following line at the end of your click event handler:

```
$("#time-line-selector").scrollLeft($(this).attr("data-id-selector") * $(this).parent().width() - $("#time-line-selector").width()/2 - $(this).parent().width()/2);
```

so it results to this:

```
$("#time-line-selector ul li a").click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $("#time-line-selector ul li a").removeClass("active");

    $(this).addClass("active");

    var yearId = $(this).attr("data-id-selector");

    $("#time-line-container ul").animate({
        "margin-left": -((yearId - 1) * timeLineContentWidth)
    }, 1000);
    $("#time-line-selector").scrollLeft($(this).attr("data-id-selector") * $(this).parent().width() - $("#time-line-selector").width()/2 - $(this).parent().width()/2);
});
```

or to eliminate the usage of data-id-selector:

```
$("#time-line-selector").scrollLeft(($(this).parent().index(".time-line-selector") + 1 ) * $(this).parent().width() - $("#time-line-selector").width()/2 - $(this).parent().width()/2);
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekv9a12j/)

Comment: You're welcome, made a quick change, so the data-id-selector does not need to be set

Comment: @Markai - can you put a link with jsfiddle. will helps a lot

Comment: I just meant, I eliminated the usage in this sceneario, so you don't rely on it, however this code relies on your data structure, and if you change the structure, you also need to change the code

Comment: @markai - Superb..!! really it's very useful code of block.

Comment: @Prog - I'm glad it helps multiple persons :)